# Add class to element if closest element contains string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some fixed HTML and I need to set a class to the element `newgroup` based on the element with the class `relatedheader`. As you can see in the HTML, the first element has a string - `Accessories`. I want to give the three elements below that element with the class `newgroup` to have class based on that string. Then I want the next set to have class from the next `relatedheader` element.

How do I do this with jQuery or vanilla JS? I guess the first step is to make the `relatedheader` element a parent?

What I got so far:

```
$('.relatedheader').nextUntil('.relatedheader').addClass('selected');
```

How do I make the script take the class dynamically releatedheader element?

```
<div class="relatedheader">
    <span class="unfoldedlabel" colspan="6">
        <a>Accessories/</a>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="newgroup"></div>
<div class="newgroup"></div>
<div class="newgroup"></div>
<div class="relatedheader">
    <span class="unfoldedlabel" colspan="6">
        <a>computers/</a>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="newgroup"></div>
<div class="newgroup"></div>
<div class="newgroup"></div>
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Im blank on this one - not sure even where to start.

Comment: quite easy with jQuery because it has some special methods to access dom elements, better to post some code which you tried although you have mentioned _im blank on this one_. That doesn't actually helping.

Comment: [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/), [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan Statred with the nextUntil, so im able to give all the element a class. Not sure how to do the rest - I cant use contains:, I want this to happen dynamically since the strings are a bit different on a few pages and nothing i can control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    $(".unfoldedlabel a").each(function(){

        if($(this).text() != "")
        {
            $(this).closest(".relatedheader").nextUntil(".relatedheader").addClass($(this).text().replace("/",""));
        }
    });
});
```

LINK To [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lmc9huu/)

Comment: That worked amazingly good, exactly what I was looking for. Tack så mycket!

Comment: Det var så lite så. Varsågod! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/baj1tap3/4/).

```
$('.relatedheader').find('a').each(function() {
   $(this).parents('.relatedheader').nextUntil('div.relatedheader').addClass('selected');
});
```

Here in the above example I'm looping through each `a` inside `.relatedheader` class and then adding `selected` class to all element until next `.relatedheader`.

**NOTE:** If you want to only add those class to next set of element as per `.relatedheader` `a` selection or some event then you can bind this functionality to that event only.

Hope this is what you need!